# (int a = DataInputStream.read(b, off, len)) less than (len) in many times

Tags: java, android, sockets, stream

I have server on computer and it's client (Android app). Client sends a big file to the server (2934822 bytes). That's code of client:

```
this.socket_out = this.socket.getOutputStream();

ByteArrayOutputStream mByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
FileInputStream mFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(mFile);
while (true) {
    byte[] i1 = new byte[65536];
    int i2 = mFileInputStream.read(i1, 0, 65536);
    Log.v("", "read=" + i2);
    if (i2 < 0) {
        mByteArrayOutputStream.close();
        mFileInputStream.close();
        break;
    } else {
        mByteArrayOutputStream.write(i1, 0, i2);
        mByteArrayOutputStream.flush();
    }
}
mFile.delete();
byte[] i1 = mByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
Log.v("", "sent=" + i1.length);
this.socket_out.write(i1);
this.socket_out.flush();
```

And logs:

> read=65536
>
> read=65536
>
> ...
>
> read=65536
>
> read=51238
>
> sent=2934822

This is code of server:

```
this.in = new DataInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());

while (
    byte[] i1 = new byte[65536];
    int i2 = this.in.read(i1, 0, 65536);
    if (i2 > -1) {
        System.out.print(i2);
        ...
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

And standart output:

> 12974
>   1440
>   1440
>   11520
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   7200
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   11520
>   1440
>   1440
>   59040
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   17280
>   ...

Why does the `DataInputStream` not reading fully 65536 bytes? How can I make it read in byte array `b` maximum count which I set in parameter `len` in `DataInputStream.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe because stream is from network and network data transfer speed is low

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with your question. The result of `read(buffer, offset, len)` cannot possibly be greater than `len`.

Comment: @EJP, my english is not too much, sorry. Change it to correct variance if you can.

Comment: Come off it. Surely you know enough English to know the difference between 'greater than' and 'less than'?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the DataInputStream not reading fully 65536 bytes?

Because there is nothing in the contract of `read()`, or `Socket`, or TCP, that says it should.

> How can I make it read in byte array b maximum count which I set in parameter len in DataInputStream.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)?

Use `DataInputStream.readFully()`, if you must, but there is no point to this, any more than there is any point in wasting time and space with the `ByteArrayOutputStream` at the sending end. The standard way to copy streams in Java is as follows:

```
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

You should use this code at both ends.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of network MTU size. Use `BufferedInputStream` around `DataInputStream`.

```
new BufferedInputStream(new DataInputStream(...
```

Or just replace `DataInputStream`by `BufferedInputStream`. Or do it the other way around `(new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream( )`. This is decorator pattern.

Comment: hmm.. I'm using `DataInputStream` because using methods `readInt()` and `readLine()`. How can I use it with `BufferedInputStream` then?

Comment: I tried `new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(...))` - no result.

Comment: network is very good. Receiving = 214mbit/sec; Send = 218mbit/sec.

Comment: Just now tried your first solution - no result. There are no difference.

Comment: Ok. I wait for monday to get the second another phone. If everything be right I accept your answer. But now I also waiting for other solutions.

Comment: How to change MTU size? I found that value is in `/sys/class/net/<?>/mtu`, where `<?>` are dirs. But I don't have permissions to edit this file. How to do it. Help.

Answer (score -1):

Data Doesnt appear magically in the buffer. It actually takes time to get transfered and your program executes faster than the big file gets transfered. 
The while loop each time grabs what is currently available in the buffer, which is these byte numbers your printing. you can check that using

```
int availableBytes = in.available();
```

and you can wait and not read the stream until a certain number of bytes becomes available in the stream for reading such as

```
while(in.available() <2000)
{}
```

but this is a blocking approach which will freeze your server until the bytes arrive. for any reason they dont, it will stay blocking forever.

Also you should Initialize your buffer like that

```
byte[] i1 = new byte[in.available()];
```

that way you dont initialize more resources than you actually need and can just read like this

```
in.read(i1);
```

without the continuous check through if statements and knowing exactly that the amount of data is

```
i1.length
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thats what I said, your just too eager. I am just showing him a way to wait for a certain amount to arrive (if he absolutely MUST)  and SAID that it will "Smoke the CPU" until the data arrives, whats your point here?? Then I said that he should initialize and process whats currently available and move on till more is in the buffer rather than block. And FYI, available() alone is non-blocking, while(in.available()<2000) IS blocking until the condition is met. And please let him decide what is to be gained, based on his application nature

Comment: It is not what you said in any way. You said it is a blocking approach. It is a polling approach. You said 'freeze', not 'smoke'. These are all completely different things.  If you don't know the difference between blocking and polling you shouldn't be answering I/O questions at all, you should be asking them. There is only one sane way to implement this code, and it is to block in read, and that fact doesn't depend on the OP in any way. Posting pointless alternatives is just pointless, and claiming that you haven't  said what you have said up there in black and white is disingenuous.

Comment: Well if we are going technical here, there is no such thing as smoking a CPU , that usually comes right about the time when physical damage occurs ... and this guy is no where near any production, and he's going through a steep learning curve ... I know what you are talking about, and the point from the polling was that he would figure out to perhaps print the available bytes and see why he's getting small chunks of data each loop and experiment and he will eventually grow out of it ... but no you just want the right answer disregarding the essence of his issue

Comment: And if you really think there is only one way of doing things and the rest are pointless ... I am sure your clueless. Sure there are better ways, however, that is decided by the situation and in his situation wasn't looking for documentation

Comment: The only thing that is sure here is that you don't understand the difference between blocking and polling, or aren't prepared to admit that you got them confused. Twice. The 'essence of his issue' demands the right answer, not irrelevance or mis-statement. I'll be happy to debate my 'cluelessness' against yours any time, but so far there is really nothing to debate.